# Wordpress Polylang language switcher links to wrong url

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I am working on my bilingual website with wordpress and the polylang plugin! The problem is that when I click on the language switcher to change from deutsch to english language the page cannot be found because it points to the wrong url (www.florian-drums.com/en instead of www.florian-drums.com/en/drumlessons). Is there a way to edit the url link from the language switcher? All other links and translation pages in the menu are working fine!

Here is the website: www.florian-drums.com

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polylang is trying to get to www.florian-drums.com/en because it is the url of the english homePage of your website, but it seems that you don't have any. Try to create a page and set it as english homePage.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I already tried that...and I already have several english pages. The problem only occurs when I first click on the language switcher. After I click on the switcher, there is this error page, but the menu changes to english and from there I can reach all english pages perfectly